# Reference Request: Fundamental Group Scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I want to learn about the Fundamental Group Scheme(First introduced by Madhav Nori). I am familiar with Basic Algebraic Geometry at the level of Eisenbud & Harris'"Geometry of Schemes" & to a lesser extent with Hartshorne's book. Can anyone suggest a good expository source for the above topic that would be accessible to me?

Comment: Questions of the form "I want to learn about ..." are rather discouraged here.

Comment: @Stefan Kohl: why? It seems to me the OP is asking a legitimate reference request (I added the appropriate tag), also specifying his background. He is not asking people to write an expository article for him, or similar stuff...

Comment: I agree that the question seems reasonable and doesn't deserve to be closed. However, my suggestion to Priyankur would be to learn a bit more algebraic geometry before jumping into this topic. At the very least, first learn a bit about the etale fundamental group from Murre's "Lectures on Grothendieck's fundamental group" TIFR.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion

T. Szamuely, Galois groups and fundamental groups.
Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 117. Cambridge University Press,

is an excellent source.